# Select2 CSS Classes

Tags: css, jquery-select2

I am using plugIn Select2 and I wanna do 2 customize in CSS:

- Change size ScrollBar of Single select. (I want resize search input -width:80%-, and make bigger scrollbar -occupy the space that has left the SearchBar-)
- Change disabled CSS Styles.

Anybody know what are their respective ClassNames? I have searching but I did not found nothing.

(eg: .select2-search input {} ; It is for Search Input)

PD: Anybody knows where can I find all CSS classes of Select2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

- Change size SearchBar Input:

  ```
  .select2-dropdown .select2-search .select2-search__field {
      width: 50% !important;     
  }
  ```
- Change Disabled Styles:

  ```
  .select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single {
      cursor: not-allowed !important;
  }

  .select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--multiple {
      cursor: not-allowed !important;
  }
  ```

If anyone knows where I can found all CSS ClassNames Select2 I will be grateful.